# Не обновляет записи mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Вот сам код:

```
<?php
    // Соединиться с сервером БД
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Выбрать БД
    mysql_select_db("poliklinika") or die(mysql_error());

    // Получить данные из БД, в зависимости от значения id в URL
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM  `cms_patients` WHERE  `PatientID` LIKE 1";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

        // Записать данные человека
        echo "<form name='forma' method='POST' action=".$_PHP_SELF.">
<div>


    <input type='text' name='LastName' placeholder='Фамилия' value='$row[LastName]'>
    <input type='text' name='FirstName' placeholder='Имя' value='$row[FirstName]'>

    <input name='update' type='submit' id='update' value='Update'>
    </div>
</form>";



    }


 ?>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{


$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "poliklinika");

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE cms_patients 
                    SET FirstName = '$row[FirstName]', LastName = '$row[LastName]' 
                    WHERE PatientID = 1");

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

}


?>
```

Выводит ошибку:

> Could not update data: Query was empty

Не силен, помогите не знаю как быть.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$connection) {
die('Не подключился : ' . mysql_error());
}
else{ 
$db_name = "poliklinika";
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_POST['LastName']!="" && $_POST['FirstName']!="" && $_POST['MidName']!=""){

$update_sql = "UPDATE cms_patients SET LastName='".$_POST['LastName']."',
FirstName='".$_POST['FirstName']."',
MidName='".$_POST['MidName']."' WHERE PatientID=1;";
mysql_query($update_sql, $connection);
echo "Данные пациента обновлены"; 
}
}
}
?>
```

Так решил свою проблему

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE cms_patients 
                    SET FirstName = '$firstname', LastName = '$lastname' 
                    WHERE PatientID = 1");
```

PS. `mysql_query` - устаревшая функция, читайте про `mysqli` и `PDO`

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но теперь другая ошибка, обновил запись. Как я понял он не может найти что обновлять